# Cannot resolve symbol Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, androidx, material-components-android, material-components

I've got an error for `'Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar'` in `styles.xml` (the `'Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar'` is colored red because of error) after several gradle update. My component are also not well arranged according to my idea of designing.

I've already clean and rebuild project, invalidate caches/restart, update the gradle (maybe not the correct answer) and there's no answer for this. I just think maybe I'm the only one that have this problem maybe for my beginner level problem :')

styles.xml

`

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/hitam</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

`

Project gradle

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

'

App gradle

```
      apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
      apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

      android {
          compileSdkVersion 29
          defaultConfig {
          applicationId "blablabla"
          minSdkVersion 23
          targetSdkVersion 29
          versionCode 1
          versionName "1.0"
          testInstrumentationRunner               "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.1'
}

compileOptions {

    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6

    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
buildToolsVersion = '29.0.1'

          }
```

`

I expect the error is not visible when there's like no one in this earth that have this error. PLEASE HELP T_T

Comment: Hi "kindkind", welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider providing a [_Minimal, Reproducible Example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you're facing so that we can help you troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Also, why are you setting the target and source compatibility of Java to multiple versions?

Comment: I already forgot why i write that code but it solved my other coding and once it solved, i considered it to be successful haha

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [Material Components themes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material-components-themes) are included in the [Material Components for Android library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Since you are using androidx library just add this dependency in you `app/build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:x.x.x'
    // ...
  }
```

Currently (April 29, 2022) the latest stable version is

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
```

Here you can find all the info [the setup](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#getting-started-with-material-components-for-android).

Comment: Hi @kindkind if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this

Comment: Ohh right, I deleted it because I didn't know I needed it, thanks.

Comment: My fix was upgrading that implementation to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the MaterialComponents theme does not show is because you did not include the required Material Components library in your `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
}
```

The currently available versions are listed on the [project's GitHub releases](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases).

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency on Android’s Material in /android/app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
    // ...
}
```

To find out the latest version, visit [Google Maven](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.google.android.material:material).

Set the theme in /android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml:

```
//<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat"> - remove
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar"> - add
```