# Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar' (Android Studio)

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

I created a new Android project using Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3 and my goal is to simply customize my app to use Material3 theme

Error occurs at **values\themes.xml** saying `Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar'`

I have found a kinda similar issue on this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57282947/cannot-resolve-symbol-theme-materialcomponents-light-noactionbar-android-studio#) but `'Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar'` was my default theme when i created the project and it had no errors, the error started when i changed to use `Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar` as per this article on [**Migrating to Material Design 3**](https://material.io/blog/migrating-material-3) under section *Migrating from M2 to M3 (MDC 1.4.0 to MDC 1.5.0)*

I have tried Sync project with gradle files, Invalidate cache /restart.. but i still get the same error

I have used [Material Theme builder](https://material-foundation.github.io/material-theme-builder/) to generate my `themes.xml` and `colors.xml` and below are my files

***themes.xml***

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_theme_light_primary</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/md_theme_light_onPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_primaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_onPrimaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/md_theme_light_secondary</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/md_theme_light_onSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_secondaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_onSecondaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorTertiary">@color/md_theme_light_tertiary</item>
        <item name="colorOnTertiary">@color/md_theme_light_onTertiary</item>
        <item name="colorTertiaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_tertiaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnTertiaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_onTertiaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorError">@color/md_theme_light_error</item>
        <item name="colorErrorContainer">@color/md_theme_light_errorContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnError">@color/md_theme_light_onError</item>
        <item name="colorOnErrorContainer">@color/md_theme_light_onErrorContainer</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/md_theme_light_background</item>
        <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/md_theme_light_onBackground</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/md_theme_light_surface</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/md_theme_light_onSurface</item>
        <item name="colorSurfaceVariant">@color/md_theme_light_surfaceVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurfaceVariant">@color/md_theme_light_onSurfaceVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOutline">@color/md_theme_light_outline</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurfaceInverse">@color/md_theme_light_inverseOnSurface</item>
        <item name="colorSurfaceInverse">@color/md_theme_light_inverseSurface</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryInverse">@color/md_theme_light_primaryInverse</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

***build.gradle (app)***

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blablabla"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0 rc1'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

***buid.gradle (project)***

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to change the dependency of your material design in your gradle file.

> Note: In order to use the new Material3 themes and component styles, you must depend on version 1.5.0-alpha04 or later.

[Getting started with MDC android](https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/getting-started)

Visit [Google's Maven Repository](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.google.android.material:material) or [MVN Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material) to find the latest version of the library.

Answer (score 5):

Just recheck your Gradle dependencies more carefully, there is a difference between

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha04'
```

and

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0-alpha01'
```

While the first one is needed for Jetpack Compose, the second one is for Android MDC. Adding the second one will fix your issue and *Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar* will be accessible from your *theme.xml* file.

Answer (score 3):

you have to use alpha version of material dependency

**Alpha Release** - This is the release when the feature which you are developing is incomplete or partially complete.

**Update your material dependency**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-alpha01'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete from gradle:
   runtimeOnly group: 'androidx.appcompat', name: 'appcompat', version: '1.7.0-alpha01'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
2. Sync
3. Add:
   runtimeOnly group: 'androidx.appcompat', name: 'appcompat', version: '1.7.0-alpha01'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
4. Sync again

Answer (score 0):

**Update your material dependency**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

**to**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0-rc01'
```